# Full Description of different Tasksel Kubuntu options?

Tags: kubuntu, 14.04, system-installation, tasksel

I've noticed that there are a few different options for Kubuntu 14.04 when you run the tasksel command. Does anyone know where I can find a fuller description of what the different options install please?

E.g. what's the difference between kubuntu-full and kubuntu-desktop?

tasksel --list doesn't give much info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:**

> what's the difference between kubuntu-full and kubuntu-desktop?

**MetaPackages**

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages

> One of the handy features of apt (the packaging system used by Ubuntu)
>   is the use of metapackages. These packages do not contain actual
>   software, they simply depend on other packages to be installed...

**kubuntu-desktop**

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/kubuntu-desktop

```
apt-cache show kubuntu-desktop

Description: Kubuntu Plasma Desktop/Netbook system
 This package depends on all of the packages in the Kubuntu desktop system.
 Installing this package will include the default Kubuntu Plasma Desktop or
 Netbook installation.
```

**kubuntu-full**

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/kubuntu-full

```
apt-cache show kubuntu-full

Description: Full Kubuntu Plasma Desktop/Netbook system
 This package depends on all of the packages in the Kubuntu DVD for a very
 complete system.  Installing this package will include much more than the
 default Kubuntu Plasma Desktop or Netbook installation.
```